# Triggered update on mysql runs second time

Tags: mysql, database, date, triggers

```
BEGIN 
SET new.Diff = DATEDIFF(new.RepairDate,new.FaultyDate);
UPDATE po
INNER JOIN xt ON po.SerialNumber = new.SerialNumber SET po.Edate = ADDDATE(po.Edate, new.Diff)
WHERE po.SerialNumber = new.SerialNumber;
END
```

This is my trigger statement. 
I want to add to Edate the integer resulted using by datediff. 
My only issue is that if I insert a test entry into the `xt` table to test this trigger nothing happens. 
If I insert the same test entry second time it works as it should have in the first try. 
After the second try everything works fine for that entry. 
Where am I doing wrong? 
please excuse me if it's a dumb question because I'm a newbie with mysql

Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance!

Comment: Need more info on trigger. Is it BEFORE|AFTER UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE and on what table? Generally speaking, triggers cannot modify data in the table they are triggers for (other than the row being modified by the trigger). Aso, I am not sure you need to JOIN in that update query at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Removing the JOIN was a solution for my problem.

Comment: I'll add it as proper answer so it can be closed out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Code within triggers cannot modify data in the table they are a trigger for, other than the row the trigger was fired for (by `SET`ting `NEW.[field]`); this means no `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` operations involving the table.

The JOIN to the trigger table was apparently the source of Ibacau's issue.